# How to show OpenFileDialog selected directory in a textbox

Tags: c#, .net, file, directory, openfiledialog

So, I set up a file browser, fully working.
But now I want to take the end location where you went and put that location into a TextBox. Which can still be typed in by the user for if they want to manually type the file location.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int size = -1;
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            try
            {
            string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
            size = text.Length;
            }
            catch (IOException) { }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(size);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
   }
```

Comment: can you please explain more detail and specific ?

Comment: Alright so basically, I have a settings tab, there I want a textBox. next to the text box I have a "Browse" button that opens a file browser. Now after the user selected the file, I want the direction of that file to show up in the text box

Answer (score 1):

You can get the full path

```
textBox1.Text = file;
```

and the last folder name

```
string lastFolderName = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(file));
textBox1.Text = lastFolderName;
```

in your code you can use like below, if you want to use the location from another scope then make `file` variable global

```
string file = "";            
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       int size = -1;
       DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
       if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
           file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
           try
           {
              string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
              size = text.Length;
              textBox1.Text = file; // for full location
              textBox2.Text = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(file)); // for last folder name
           }
           catch (IOException)
           {
           }
       }
    }
```

and then

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           textBox2.Text = file;
        }
```

Comment: So, textBox1.Text = file;
 goes under the TextBox where I want the dir to show up?

Comment: yes it is the textBox where you want to show the dir

Comment: For some reason  with textBox1.Text = file;
file doesn't exist in current context

As of right now I got: http://imgur.com/QhMNLL9

Comment: you have done everything insdie a button click event and tryig to acccess this from another textchange event, thats not allowed, you have to make the file variable global scope, at present it is in local scope

Comment: And how would I do that?
+ You're amazing for all the help. Thanks

Comment: but keep in mind don't put the text in same textBox insdie its TextChange event, because it will create a loop like your image `textBox1.Text = file` insdie its own text change event, I have made the `textBox2.Text = file` in my answer

Comment: Alright, so now I have: http://imgur.com/SvecFVq If you were wondering what the design looked like: http://imgur.com/uqEVF2y For some reason it says OpenFileDialog1 does not exist.

Comment: did you add `openFileDialog` from the tool menu as the same way you added `textbox`, if not add an  `openFileDialog` from the tool menu, you will find it under Tools men Dialog section or all control section, after adding hope this error will go

Comment: Seems like it works now. But what I also want is I want that to stay in the textBox1. Cause basically it's a settings tab that's opened by a button on the main menu. But when I close it and open it again it dissapears. Any idea how I make it stay?

Comment: what you want to stay ? the text in the text box ? next time when you open the window the text need to remain in the textbox ?

Comment: Yeah, what you just said.

Comment: for that, you have to save the path of the file in another text file when you are reading it using `openFileDialog` in `button1_Click` event and in the setting window load event read that text and put it in the `textBox1.Tex` that will show the path every time you open the setting window

Comment: try this if you can't make it then accept this answer and ask another question about it I will try to answer that

Comment: Don't really get it, i'll make another question and edit link in this comment
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37103859/windows-form-app-saving-info